# extra words after "else" clause in "if" command for TCL code

Tags: if-statement, tcl

I have a tcl code where -

```
    if { $xyz == 43 } {
       # 1. Set some variables
       set my_filename_log "somename_log.txt"
       if {[file exists $my_filename_log ]} {
           file delete -force $my_filename_log 
       }
    } # end of xyz = 43
```

I am getting error as - TCLERROR: wrong # args: extra words after "else" clause in "if" command while compiling -
 if { $xyz == 43 } {
           # 1. Set some variables...
Not sure what is wrong with this code, checked tcl documentation didnt find anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Tcl`, for else if condition should be written without space as `elseif`. Otherwise you will get the error you have mentioned.

```
if {$xyz==1} {
        puts "Yes"
} else if {$xyz==2} {
        puts "No"
}

wrong # args: extra words after "else" clause in "if" command
```

In your code, you have used

```
} # end of xyz = 43
```

at the last line. You have to use `;` to mark the end of the statements and then you can start the comments with `#`.

So, your code should be written as,

```
if { $xyz == 43 } {
   # 1. Set some variables
   set my_filename_log "somename_log.txt"
   if {[file exists $my_filename_log ]} {
       file delete -force $my_filename_log 
   }
}; # end of xyz = 43
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about `elseif` but didn't know about using `;` before starting comments.